# systemd service file closing socket

Tags: bash, systemd, socket, c++

I need to run a C++ binary with systemd.

When I execute the binary directly or with a `bash` script it runs fine for days:

- `nohup ./testbinary &`
- `./test.sh`

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/test01/lib/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/test01/testbinary
```

But when I execute this script with the following systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=cr06

Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/test01/test.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It runs for some time, like 6 to 7 minutes, then it gives errors, and I need to restart the service.

The socket connection that this binary is making to other applications fails. It only happens when the binary is executed as a systemd service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is running fine by just adding LimitNOFile=5000 to script file

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things in your scenario:

1. You are calling `./test.sh` instead of `/home/test01/testbinary`.  This makes me think the working directory may be important to your `testbinary`.  If your testbinary uses relative paths, then it may have a problem finding resources or writing files.  Try specifying the working-directory in the `[Service]` section of your unit.

   ```
   WorkingDirectory=/home/test01
   ```
2. Your service runs as `root` while your test ran as `$USER`.  While `root` can normally do anything, it's possible that your program creates `AF_UNIX` sockets which are not readable/writable by the other process (who are run as non-root).

   In this case try adding this to the `[Service]` section of your unit.

   ```
   User=test01
   ```

I don't think `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a factor here.  If it was a factor, the program would fail immediately with `exit-status (203)` and a nice message telling you which library failed to load.